# Cannot find Mercurial global configuration file on osx

Tags: macos, mercurial

I am new to [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/). I am trying to setup my computer to access [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) [using the following instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678). On `Step 5`, I am told to add `ssh = ssh -C` to file `~/.hgrc`. I can't seem to find the file. Has anyone done this step successfully? How do I go about it?

Comment: Have you used Mercurial on that machine before? Do you see anything if you run cat ~/.hgrc from the command line?

Comment: @Timo Geusch I get `.hgrc: No such file or directory`. No this is the first I have heard of mercurial in fact.

Comment: If you haven't used Mercurial before you won't have the configuration file, that's why you're not seeing it. Lazy Badger's answer should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you don't have `Mercurial` installed at all. [`Step 3`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=269981802) of Bitbucket tutorial gives detailed description  how to install it from `MacPorts`.

Once you have `Mercurial` installed just create `.hgrc` manually and add your configuration.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. When I went to Step 3 ( https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=269981802 ), I didn't see anything that explained what `MacPorts` is or how to use it. I just followed the tutorial and dowloaded mercurial from http://mercurial.selenic.com/ and everything turned out fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not this file - create it. But you, maybe, **just can't** see it - dotted files are hidden. Anyway read `hg help config`

Comment: I already tried `hg help config`. I got `command not found`. Is this a software I must install? Do I really need it for Gitbucket? Can I install it with macports?

Comment: @learner There are [binary packages](http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads/) available of Mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with this too, but managed to find the .hgrc file. First get all hidden files visible by downloading this software http://invisiblix.read-write.fr/

Initially I tried to find the .hgrc file with spotlight but nothing came up. Happened to spotlight "~/", then this "~/.config" folder appeared, so I went there and found .hgrc in the same directory. Somehow it's always there but just not appearing even when called for in terminal.